# CREATE TABLE with PRIMARY KEY on TINYTEXT column causes error: MySQL #1071 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 255 bytes'

Tags: mysql, dreamhost

I haven't coded PHP for a while now. My website, that I wrote in PHP some time ago, that is running from a shared hosting company, started giving me the following error in the log when the script was executing the following query via `mysql_query`:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (idx TINYTEXT, PRIMARY KEY(idx(255)))
```

and the error itself:

> MySQL #1071 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 255 bytes'

It worked for many years. So what's the problem there now?

Comment: What's the character set of the DB (Try `SELECT @@character_set_database`)? Probably some with more than one byte per character?

Comment: @stickybit: I don't know. I don't have direct access to the DB. It's running from the PHP script on the shared web hosting provider. Is there a way to write it agnostic to the encoding?

Comment: I depends on the characterset.  look it up with SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%'; For example mysql 8 brings that an error as long you use numbers greater than 63, because it can only hold  63 4-byte characters when your characterset is utf8mb4.

Comment: @nbk: why do I need to know all this for my query? Is there a way to specify maximum available, whatever the value is?

Comment: depening on the characterset you can choose bigger numbers. And of course ou can use sticky_bits algorithm. Buts it doesn't matter if you need 255 you should alter your table

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum key length is 255 bytes and you are using UTF8 encoding, then each character can be up to 4 bytes.

Hence, the maximum is 63 bytes.  This works:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    idx TINYTEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (idx(63))
);
```

Comment: but what if I'm adding 255 ASCII chars `A`?

Comment: That doesn't matter.  MySQL has to prepare for the worst.

Comment: I don't understand then. Why did that same statement work before? I only started seeing those error messages in about a few months ago.

Comment: @c00000fd . . . Did something change with the version of MySQL or the storage engine?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the catalog in particular the [`information_schema.character_sets` table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/character-sets-table.html) to get the maximum length a character can have in a given character set. From that you can calculate the maximum number of characters not exceeding 255 bytes.

```
SELECT floor(255 / maxlen) maxcharlen
       FROM information_schema.character_sets
       WHERE character_set_name = @@character_set_database;
```

You can then amend your `CREATE` statement based on that value.